# PHP/MySQL selecting from table based on list of items from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how do you select a list of items from one table based on another list of items from another table?
For example, I have two tables :

-buddies
--usera
--userb

-News
--id
--message
--timestamp
--userid

I'm wondering how do you get all the messages from news of people who are only friends of a specific user.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_join

Answer (score 2):

This question is way too vague for StackOverflow. In the spirit of vagueness I'll answer your question with an equally vague answer: You can accomplish this with [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) and/or the [IN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) keyword. In the future, be sure to look up [how to ask a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and be sure to tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` clause in SQL:

```
select *
  from news
 where userid in (select userb
                    from buddies
                   where usera=specified_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM news 
LEFT JOIN buddies ON buddies.userid = news.userid
WHERE buddies.userid='usera'
AND news.userid='userb'
```

that should give you all the "news" for user A that was posted by user B.